# Wicked page flash when using Ajax

Tags: wicket

I start a thread from wicket and refresh a page every 5 secondes to check if the computed data are available. when it's the case, the result is displayed.

The problem is that the page flash every 5 secondes. with firebug, I found the xml response is 
`<ajax-response></ajax-response>`

I use the AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior and AbstractBehavior to use Ajax and I'm using wicket 1.4.9.

Comment: As an aside: Try to work with the latest Wicket version now, rather than later. 6.9.1 is out as of July 2013.

Comment: Thanks tim, but unfortunately, i can't upgrade to the last version.

Comment: in the target.addComponent(...) section of your ajax refresh, only add the component that needs to be refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

That flash is your page refreshing. You might want to change the behavior from refreshing the page to refreshing the component, that will be displaying the computed data. As long as there is no data or the component isn't visible there will be no noticeable flashing.

Comment: I'm adding the behaviour to a component and not to the webpage, is there something else that i have to do so the refreshing will be only in the block?

Comment: What do you add to the AjaxRequestTarget?

Comment: Nothing if the data aren't computed. and still, there is a page refresh.